# how to check whether any special character is present in a particular string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the '<' '>' from the string so i used the script

```
<html>
<body>

 <script>
  var f = ((/(<script>)/i).exec("hello<") != null);
  alert("ok"+f);

  document.write("<br>Value:" +f);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i'm getting the variant f value as null..

Could you please help me.if there is any issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
if("hello<".indexOf('<') != -1){
     var f = "hello<".replace('<','');
     alert("ok "+f);   
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you JavaScript regular expressions to achieve this.

```
"<script>".replace(/<|>/ig, "");
outputs: "script"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var f = ('<script>'.replace(/<|>/g, ''));
  alert("ok"+f);

  document.write("<br>Value:" +f);
```

Comment: But i need to print an alert message while these characters are inside the string. before replacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.test` method:

```
​var originalString = '<script>',
    r = originalString.test(/<|>/g, ''); // returns true or false

if (r === true) {
  //whatever you wanna do if you have special characters in 
  // your string
} else {
  // no special chars - all clean!
}
```